# Equation for geodesic on saddle shaped plane

Tags: geometry, surfaces, geodesic

I'm working on a visualization project in javascript regarding the curvature of the universe. As part of this I'm drawing a saddle shaped plane (negative curvature) and I'd like to draw a geodesic triangle on top of the plane. For reference, I'm trying to recreate the middle figure in [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/End_of_universe.jpg)

I cannot figure out what the geodesic lines on my saddle shape are, and I'd like help.

The saddle in question is 
$$z = \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{r}$$

where $r$ is an arbitrary parameter. I'm hoping to find an equation for the geodesic line between two arbitrary points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$  where the $z$ coordinate is defined by the surface. Ideally, I'd like something in parametric form so I can graph it on a computer easily.

I have a hunch that the geodesic is a hyperbola but I can't figure out its form.
Any advice is much appreciated!

EDIT:
I ended up finding a workaround by using mathematica to list points on the geodesic line a la (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103624/geodesics-on-torus), then loading those points into my webpage from a csv file

Comment: Google "geodesics on quadrics".

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S1402925109000108).